# Can't see events

Tags: civievent, drupal, drupal-views

After recent update (I think to 5.10.2) events don't show up. Interestingly, I can see the pager (1 2 next last) but not the events themselves. I *can* see the events in the Event Dashboard.

When I try to `Edit View` in Drupal, I see the following error

> `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM civicrm.civicrm_event civicrm_event LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0' at line 1`

and all fields show `Broken/missing handler`

I am pretty sure it could be a clue - but how can I see the actual SQL that is throwing the error? There is nothing in the log file

I update both Drupal and Civi to the latest versions (7.64 and 5.10.4) but no impact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the SQL query when in edit mode of the view, select the ‘Show the SQL query’ option here - /admin/structure/views/settings

This may assist –

1. Clear views’ cache - /admin/structure/views/settings/advanced
2. If that doesn’t fix it then update your settings.php file if you have separate databases - https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/views/#drupal-7

Clear CiviCRM/Drupal caches.

Comment: I forgot to clear views' cache...